# I get a compile error with JerseyClientBuilder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I am using IntelliJ.
I have added the JAR - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.0-m04
To my project,

```
{{ import org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder; }}
```

despite this I still get a compile error .

```
Error:(3, 35) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JerseyClientBuilder
  location: package org.glassfish.jersey.client
```

I did have a lot of errors due to missing JARS , but I just found them on the web and added them to the project under project structure and that sorted all the errors except for the jersey Client Builder ...

Comment: you need to add dependency in `build.gradle` file

Comment: There is no such file in the folder or any subfolders. - sorry maybe I should explain better, I am on Windows 10 and just building a simple command line app ..

Comment: Ah !!  POM file ... got it !!